# How to get the result of a Saga?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Let's say I have a modal with a button that dispatches an action if you click on it. And I'd like to know the result of the action dispatched: e.g. if it was successful I'll close the modal and to something different otherwise.
With redux-thunk my action would look something like:

```
export const deleteObjects = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      ...
      dispatch(setObjects([]));
      return true
    } catch (e) {
      return false
    }
  }
};
```

so I could use the result in my component. But how to do the same with redux-sagas? As far as I know, you can use sagas with watchers. 
One solution I could think of is to pass a callback function to the action creator and call it inside of saga. Like this:

```
export const deleteObjects = (callback) => ({
  type: DELETE_OBJECTS,
  callback
});

export function* deleteObjectsAsync({callback}) {
  try {
    ...
    put(setObjects([]))
    yield call(callback, true)
  } catch (err) {
    yield call(callback, false)
  }
}


function* watchGetPlaces() {
  yield takeEvery(DELETE_OBJECTS, deleteObjectsAsync)
}
```

Is this a valid solution or there is a more adequate way to do so?

Comment: I dont think i understand. If your modal gets affected by outside state for example a flag isOpen then when the result affect the reducer your isOpen will turn false. and modal will close. Am i on the right track of your needs?

Comment: @jstuartmilne Not quite, the question is not about closing a modal but about the result of the action dispatched. I'd like to get some feedback from it (like in the example with thunk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend your proposed solution.  Passing callback functions is one of the precise things redux-saga tries to prevent the developer to have to deal with.

One clean solution is to wrap your modal closing functionality into its own saga that can be invoked by an action.  I'm not sure how you open your modals, but on our apps we dispatch actions to open and close modals.  Doing this enables connected components *and* sagas can manipulate any modal.  Sagas are designed to handle **side effects**.  Closing a modal is a side effect.  Therefore, a saga is a perfect place to put closing modal logic.

Check out this boilerplate:

```
export const closeModal = () => ({
  type: CLOSE_MODAL,
});
function* onCloseModal() {
  // Your logic for closing modals goes here
}
function* closeModalSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(CLOSE_MODAL, onCloseModal)
}

export const deleteObjects = () => ({
  type: DELETE_OBJECTS,
});
export function* deleteObjectsAsync() {
  try {
    ...
    yield put(setObjects([]))
    yield put(closeModal());
  } catch (err) {
    // Your "do-something-else" logic here
    // I'd recommend dispatching another action
  }
}
function* watchGetPlaces() {
  yield takeEvery(DELETE_OBJECTS, deleteObjectsAsync)
}
```

Comment: What about changing routes with, say, react-router? Would that go into the saga as well?

Comment: Absolutely.  Changing routes is a side effect.  You can invoke `browserHistory.push(route)` in a saga.  An easy way to test this is `call`ing it.  i.e.  `yield call(browserHistory.push, route);` (`import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';`)

Comment: do you use something like `react-router-redux` / `connected-react-router` ?